# How can I cut down on the number of events that are fired when a key is pressed in ckEditor?

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I am using ckEditor and have a directive containing:

```
    ck.on('key', function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
            console.log("Updating the model - key - " + attr['name']);
        });
    });
```

This picks up every change to mode and key click inside the editor and updates the model.

However I notice that these changes are slowing down data entry. Is there a way that I could still catch every keypress but not have so many updates to the model. I was thinking of some kind of a timeout but I am not sure how I could implement that.

Comment: CKEditor already implements such feature. See: [CKEDITOR.tools.eventsBuffer](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.tools-method-eventsBuffer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative method that doesn't use intervals. Each time a key is pressed, start a 1s timeout and after that perform the update. If a key is pressed more often than 1s, making it too fast, just reset the timer. You can use the same timer and same update function for other events too, making this nice an scalable.

```
function update() {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
        console.log("Updating the model - key - " + attr['name']);
    });
}

var timeout = 1000, timer;

ck.on('key', function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        update();
    }, timeout);
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to update every n seconds when a key is pressed, you could do something like this.

```
var timeout = 1000, timer, updating = false;

function update() {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
        console.log("Updating the model - key - " + attr['name']);
        updating = false;
    });
}

ck.on('key', function () {
    if (updating === true) return;
    updating = true;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        update();
    }, timeout);
});
```

However, if you need to check if content has changed and not if a key is pressed, you could use `ck.checkDirty()` and `ck.resetDirty()` to do the checking combined with an interval. There is also a `change` event, but I haven't tested it. There are many different content changes that do not trigger the `key` event, such as bolding some text, adding image or HR via icon, changing table properties, and dragging an image for example.

Comment: Interesting solution, however the only problem I can see is if the model needs to update continuously, and the user is typing faster than the timeout, it will only update once you stop typing - only a minor niggle though, and much tidier than mine!

Comment: @BCotter Ach I see, I did not take that into account, this sort of method is not very good in that case indeed, I might have to think of something else, thanks for the comment!

Comment: Meh.. the updated solution has a race condition-like issue if a `key` event fires  when `update()` is still happening, but it shouldn't be that bad if `update()` is synchronous, which I'm guessing it is.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this would be to wrap a set interval in a set timeout on keydown, which would allow you to keep updating and applying, but only if they've typed recently.

Something like this

```
   var x = setInterval(function() {
       $scope.$apply(function () {
           ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
       });
   }, 200);

   ck.on('key', function () {
   if (!x) {
        x = setInterval(function() {
       $scope.$apply(function () {
           ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
       });
   }, 200);
   };
   setTimeout(function() {
       window.clearInterval(x), 2000
   });   
});
```

However, I haven't tested this code, but if you want to put up a fiddle with the situation you're describing, I can do some testing.

Edit: Just realised previous method would create intervals for each callback scope.